# with web server write access in php ( moodle )

Tags: php, .htaccess, moodle

i use moodle ( is a learning management system ), and this cms need to `.htaccess`
 with his content . content of my `.htaccess` file is :

```
deny from all
AllowOverride None
Note: this file is broken intentionally, we do not want anybody to undo it in subdirectory!
```

but when i see my site i face this message :

> You need to create the directory mdldata19 with web server write access

there is `.htaccess` in 'mdldata19' directory.
is better content for this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing directory probably has nothing to do with .htaccess, but rather Moodle requires a writable directory called `mdldata19`.

Create a directory `mdldata19` whereever the documentation specifies it be created, and make it writable by the web server user.  On Apache systems, this is usually a user called `www-data`, `apache`, `httpd`, or others. You would need to find out the user Apache is running under by looking for the following directive in httpd.conf:

```
User <apacheusername>
Group <apachegroupname>
```

Then change the directory's group ownership to the Apache user and make it group-writable

```
chown yourusername:apachegroup mdldata19
chmod g+rwx mdldata19
```